# TinyMCE v6 - how to replace <u> by <span style="text-decoration: underline">

Tags: html, tinymce

I have a tinyMCE component. The underline is made with  in tiny. I want to automatically change all `<u>` in `<span style="text-decoration: underline">`.

I know that you can ask tiny to automatically change some markups in others, with the "valid-elements". It works with the following code for "storng" and "em", but not for the underline: `valid_elements: "#p,strong,b,em,i,u,span[style=text-decoration: underline],span[style=text-decoration: underline]/u,strong/b,em/i"` Is there any other way to do this? ==> when the richtext has `<u>underlined text</u>` it automatically change and save as `<span style="text-decoration:underline">underlined text</span>`. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using the [style formats](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@style_formats/) in your init section.  Something like the following:

```js
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    style_formats : [
        // use the following for inline style - not exactly sure on the syntax for text decoration
        {title : 'Underline', inline : 'span', styles : {textDecoration : 'underline'}}, 
        // or use the following if you want to add a class
        {title : 'Underline', inline : 'span', classes : 'underline'},  
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. But it was not exactly what I wanted to do.
We found a way to do it :

```
valid_elements:'tmpunderline/u[style~text-decoration:underline], span/tmpunderline[style]'
```

We have to create a temporary variable with specific style to make the change.